# Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False" just doesn't work to hide the title bar

Tags: c#, maui, ui-design

I've basically got a Maui default test app, but I just can't figure out how I can remove the navigation bar.

[image]

I just want the gray text to be gone, and no place occupied by it (e.g. in the example, the car should be at the top of the screen).

I've tried (in `Styles.xaml`)

```xml
  <Style TargetType="Shell" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
      <Setter Property="Shell.NavBarHasShadow" Value="False" />
      <Setter Property="Shell.NavBarIsVisible" Value="False" />
  </Style>
```

and in `AppShell.xaml`

```xml
<Shell
    x:Class="MauiTest.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiTest"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout"
    Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
    Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False">
....
</Shell>
```

and the same also in `MainPage.xaml` and even via C#, but nothing has any effect whatsoever (other changes are applied, so it's not a build issue).

I'm currently only testing on Windows. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it. The extended example I was looking at to see how to add more pages changed the constructor in `App` as follows:

```cs
public App(INavigationService navigationService)
{
    NavigationService = navigationService;
    InitializeComponent();
    MainPage = new NavigationPage();
    // ...
}
```

Changing that back to `MainPage = new AppShell()` (as it is in the standard example) fixed the issue. I'm still discovering Maui, so I don't really know yet what all these classes do.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I will, but I still need to wait 1 hour until I can...

Answer (score 1):

I created a new project but can not reproduce your problem. And I **added the background color for the Image.**

Before adding the `Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"` in the AppShell:

[image]

After adding the `Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"` in the AppShell:

[image]

You can see the `Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"` worked the Image Control was at the top of the screen.

You can also add the BackgroundColor for the Image Control to check it. I'm using Visual Studio version 17.9.0 Preview 1.1 and tested it on Windows 11.

Comment: Oh... I'm really confused now. It works for me if I go back to the very first version. But with some simple added views it no longer works. Looks like I need to track down what change broke it.

Comment: I will help you if you can provide a samll sample or the detail steps to reproduce the problem. @PMF

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out myself (see answer below). I'm sure I'll run into more issues later, though ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand upon the other answers here, if you wanted to *also* remove the native Title Bar when running in Windows, I've had some luck using P/Invoke to do that. Here's my all-in-one code:

- Hide Navigation Bar
- Remove System Menu
- Resize to a "mobile" aspect ratio.

[image: screenshot]

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new AppShell();
    }

#if WINDOWS
    protected override Window CreateWindow(IActivationState? activationState)
    {
        Window window = base.CreateWindow(activationState);

        window.HandlerChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if(sender is Window mauiWindow && mauiWindow.Handler is IElementHandler handler) 
            {
                Shell.SetNavBarIsVisible(Shell.Current, false);
                Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
                {
                    if (handler.PlatformView is Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window nativeWindow)
                    {
                        var hWnd = nativeWindow.GetWindowHandle();
                        int style;
                        style = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
                        style &= ~(WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU);
                        SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, style);
                    }
                    window.Width = 540;
                    window.Height = 960;
                });
            }
        };
        return window;
    }
#endif


    private const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
    private const int WS_CAPTION = 0xC00000;
    private const int WS_SYSMENU = 0x80000;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowLong")]
    private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLong")]
    private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong); 
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. I might need this later (the application should be able to optionally run in fullscreen mode)